# How to (properly) update a worker QThread with new connection settings?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

Suppose I have a QThread for running a plugin in my app and the plugin connects to a server specified by the user. When the user changes the server settings, the plugin should connect to the new server - as expected. Would it be a good idea to simply terminate the current plugin worker thread and spin up a new one when the user updates the settings?

This is what I've got at the moment

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        # ...
        self.hostname.editingFinished.connect(
            lambda: self._setup_new_server() or
                    self._restart_plugin_work_thread()
            )
        self.port.editingFinished.connect(
            lambda: self._setup_new_server() or
                    self._restart_plugin_work_thread()
            )

    def _create_plugin_worker_thread(self):
        self.plugin_worker_thread = QtCore.QThread()
        self.plugin_worker = PluginWorker()
        self.plugin_worker.moveToThread(self.plugin_worker_thread)
        self.plugin_worker_thread.start()
        self.plugin_worker.run_plugin_signal.connect(self.plugin_worker.run_plugin)
        self.plugin_worker.stop_plugin_signal.connect(self.plugin_worker.stop_run_plugin)

    def _terminate_plugin_worker_thread(self):
        self.plugin_worker_thread.terminate()

    def _restart_plugin_work_thread(self):
        # terminate the current worker thread
        self._terminate_plugin_worker_thread()
        # create a new worker thread
        self._create_plugin_worker_thread()

class PluginWorker(QtCore.QObject):
    run_plugin_signal = QtCore.Signal(str, int, str, str)
    stop_plugin_signal = QtCore.Signal()
    # ...
```

`PluginWorker` is the worker class which mostly relies on a `QTimer` that triggers the plugin's execution method every 2 seconds.
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are several solutions.  Though I haven't worked with QT.

If it was my code I would kill the thread and start a new one with the updated connection settings.

At thread construction pass a threading.Event object to the thread and also hold a reference from the main thread.  When the connection string is updated set the event and create a new thread (passing a new event object).  Within the thread function return if the event has been set.

Comment: I think what you've described is very much the same as what I'm trying to achieve. I just wonder if what I've done is the QT way of handling threads. Also, whether I'm terminating the thread properly.